# Can I still use Ubuntu 12.04 which I find to be secure and stable?

Tags: 12.04

After I installed  Ubuntu 14.04, I started to have several problems like applications crashing and slow system. I tried using other Ubuntu flavors like Xubuntu, Kubuntu and Gnome classic, but I didn't like them.

I would like to know if can I use Ubuntu 12.04 instead since I found it to be more stable on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still use 12.04 LTS, as it will be supported until April 2017. Don't forget to install updates regularly if possible.

However, 12.04 lacks some new features which are making 14.04 more comfortable to use. Perhaps you should try to debug your 14.04 issues so you can take advantage of them.

---

**Edit:** It is September 2017 now, way past the end of life date of 12.04 LTS unless you pay for support. So there will be no security updates for regular users of the free version of Ubuntu. See this link,

[www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)

[How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)